# Differentiation of $\sin^2\left(\frac{\arccos x}{2}\right)$

Tags: derivatives

I'm unable to differentiate 
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\arccos x}{2}\right)$$
Please help me with it.

Comment: Which kind of problem do you run into? It should be a simple matter of applying the relevant rules (esp. the chain rule)  mechanically.

Comment: Ak19 gave you a nice hint, but you can also differentiate it as it is written using the rules, $$(\sin(u))'= u'\sin(u)$$, $$(v^n)'=nv'v^{n-1}$$ and $$(\arccos x)'=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Alternatively you can use trig identities to show that the function you want to differentiate actually equals $\frac12-\frac12x$ on its domain...

Answer (score 4):

Hint

$$\sin^2\bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)  = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}$$